# How do i access a dynamically generated ng-model value of an input field using $scope.$watch in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I want to access a dynamically generated angular-ngmodel
      value of an input field using $scope.$watch.
      This is my code snippet below:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="<?php echo $product->id ?>" name="prid" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" ng-click="yea()"/>
    </form>
</body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.yea = function() {
            $scope.$watch('xxx', function(){
                var test = angular.copy($scope.xxx);
                alert(test);
            })
        };
    });
</script>
```

What I want to do actually: i want to get the dynamic generated value of
     the text field above, then pass it through angularJS to a php variable.
     So, I thought of the code above but got stucked (do not know what the xxx
     wud be). Please, am I doing it the wrong way or is there any solution to 
     the code above?

Thanks

Comment: ng-model of text field is not closed

Comment: Your JS and HTML code are in the same file ? If yes you could just do `$scope.$watch('<?php echo $product->id ?>', function() {...`

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own directive:

```
<my-input my-input-id="{{'<?php echo $product->id ?>'}}"></my-input>
```

This way php should replace its code with the id, which you will then be able to use in your directive:

```
app.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        myInputId: '@'
      },
      template: '<input ng-model="myInputId" />'
  };
});
```

Note that I haven't tested if this code really works. If you would create a plunkr or jsfiddle, I will be more than happy to take a look.

But I would personally never print out php in a way like this. Whenever I worked with PHP and Angular, I did HTTP calls from Angular to a PHP API. This way you have a clear separation between your Angular and PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngInit` to initialize your model, like

```
<input type="text" ng-init="initPrid(<?php echo $product->id ?>)" ng-model="prId" name="prid" />
```

And then inside your controller add

```
$scope.initPrid = function(id) {
  $scope.prId = id;
};
```